# List all files and date modified in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I know how to use the Get Metadata activity in ADF, but that only gets me the metadata of that folder and the folders/filenames it contains.  How do I get the metadata of all the filenames within a parent folder which can have inconsistent subfolders?

For example in my parent folder Tommy, it can have Folder A and Folder B.

Folder A can contain the parquet files I want to list, but Folder B can have another folder inside which contains the parquet files I also want to list.

In the end I just want a list of all parquet folders within Tommy, so that my output will look something like this:

```
[
 {
  "name": "Tommy/Folder A/File1.snappy.parquet",
  "lastModified": "2023-09-29T10:09:27Z"
  },
 {
  "name": "Tommy/Folder B/Folder C/File2.snappy.parquet",
  "lastModified": "2023-09-29T10:09:27Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the procedure below to obtain the desired output:

1. Create a source dataset with the required path. Use the `Get Metadata` activity to list the folders in the container, as shown below:

[image]

2. Assign the activity output to the `items` array variable using the following expression:

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
```

[image]

3. Add a `foreach` activity with `@variables('items')`. Inside the loop, use the `Get Metadata` activity to get the last modified date with the dataset and the `name` parameter, as shown below:

[image]

4. Use another `Get Metadata` activity to get child items in folders, as shown below:

[image]

5. Assign the activity output to the `lf` array variable using the following expression:

```
@activity('Get Metadata3').output.childItems
```

[image]

6. You can use the `append variable` `lastm` with the expression below:

```
@concat(variables('lf'),' ','Lastmodified:',activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified)
```

[image]

7. Assign the `foreach` activity output to the `result` array variable using the `@variables('lastm')` expression, as shown below:

[image]

8. After debugging the pipeline, you can get the output as shown below:

[image]